# Cannot find protocol declaration for <RKObjectLoaderDelegate>

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I tried to setup RestKit using cocoapod following [this instruction](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-restkit-v0.20.x-via-cocoapods).
Everything looks fine. I can import RestKit and build the project.
However, when I added `<RKObjectLoaderDelegate>` to the `ViewController` interface, I got the error: Cannot find protocol declaration for `RKObjectLoaderDelegate`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you `#import "RKObjectLoader.h"` in your header?

Comment: well, RKObjectLoader.h file not found. I thought cocoapod would take care of all dependencies. Did I do something wrong? How should I fix this?

Comment: You need to bring in the header that contains `RKObjectLoaderDelegate`. I don't see that protocol anywhere in the RestKit source. Are you sure it even exists?

Comment: Alright, sorry my bad. I think the tutorial I followed uses the old version (0.10.0). And the protocol was probably removed. Thanks. (note: http://restkit.org/api/0.10.0/Protocols/RKObjectLoaderDelegate.html)

Comment: For further notice, RESTKit received a tremendous update on december/2012 and everything on object mapping from prior versions stopped working.